# cmake and make fail to find local glm installation despite finding system wide one

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, cmake, compilation

I am trying to compile a program on linux with cmake. I have glm installed as a system library and the code compiles links and runs just fine.

However due to some portability issues I have faced I want to make it so that the glm installation is local (i.e a folder inside the project).

When I try doing it this way the compiler crashese with error message:

```
fatal error: glm/ext/vec1.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <glm/ext/vec1.hpp>
```

GLM itself is inside of a directory in the project directory

[image]

And  I am including it in the cmake lists file through:

```
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_package` simply sets some variables; you still need to tell your targets where to find glm. The official [glmConfig.cmake](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/cmake/glmConfig.cmake.in) defines a `GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, which you should add to a target as

```
target_include_directories(myTarget ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```